# Tempus-dominus and sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sweetalert2, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I've created a modal with [sweetalert2](http://sweetalert2.github.io) and the input field is a datepicker widget from [tempusdominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) but the calendar shows behind the buttons of the modal as the following image:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
Swal.fire({
   title: 'Pay',
   html: '<input type="text" name="payment_day" class="datetimepicker-input swal2-input" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#payment_day" id="payment_day">',
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
   cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
   confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
   cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
   onOpen: function () {
     $('#payment_day').datetimepicker({
       format: 'L'
     });
   },
}).then((result) => {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and now :

```js
$(function() {
  Swal.fire({
   title: 'Pay',
   html: '<input type="text" name="payment_day" class="datetimepicker-input swal2-input" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#payment_day" id="payment_day">',
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
   cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
   confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
   cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
   onOpen: function () {
     $('#payment_day').datetimepicker({
       format: 'L'
     });
   },
}).then((result) => {});
});
```

```css
.swal2-content
{
      z-index: 2!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>


<link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: so just make sure that the z-index of your calendar is bigger than the z-index of the buttons ?

Comment: I tried adding the following: 
```        .swal2-content {
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .swal2-actions {
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
            z-index: 2;
            position: static;
        }
``` 
But still not working..

Comment: you just forgot to add important to your property! check my answer again.

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While you can apply styles to `.swal2-content`, it is not the recommended way to do it because `.swal2-content` is the internal class name and it could be changed at any point (very unlikely, but still).

The correct way to handle this would be to use the `customClass` parameter to add your custom class with `z-index`:

```js
Swal.fire({
  customClass: {
    popup: 'my-swal',
    content: 'my-swal-content'
  }
})
```

```css
.my-swal .my-swal-content {
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```